# Led potlights stopped working for 1 section

Tags: electrical

3 years ago I added 8 new led potlights to an exiting kitchen ceiling that had 6 led potlights.

They worked perfectly until 2 weeks ago, when the new potlights would be delayed when switched on with the rest ( on the same switch).

Now the 8 new potlights have power along the path except at the led light housing. The wires to the led light housing has power,  just no power at the led light; even though the led light fixture will work when I replace at an original led potlight location (original 6).

Confused as to why they won't turn on?
[image]

[image]

Comment: I would look for a loose connection(hot and neutral) between the 6 and 8.  Might have power, but do you have enough.  A loose connection might drop the voltage below 90v.